# UDF VBA producing zeros. No error values, just zeros. Can someone please check my code

Tags: vba, user-defined-functions

'VBA function is calculate the 1 year forward rate in 0.5, 1, 1.5 and 2 years etc. All results are zero; no error values, just zeros. Can anybody advise where I'm going wrong. Thanks

```
Function OneYearFwdRates(Mty As Range, Spots As Range) As Variant
Dim Maturities()
ReDim Maturities(Mty.Rows.Count)  'Mty is the range of maturities'
Dim SpotRates()
ReDim SpotRates(Spots.Rows.Count)  'Spots is the range of spot rates'
Dim OYFR()                         'OYFR stands for One Year Forward Rates'
ReDim OYFR(Spots.Rows.Count)
Dim i

For i = 2 To Spots.Rows.Count - 2
    OYFR(i) = (1 + SpotRates(i + 2)) ^ (Maturities(i + 2)) _
        / (1 + SpotRates(i)) ^ (Maturities(i)) - 1
Next i
OneYearFwdRates = OYFR

End Function
```

Below is the spreadsheet. I want to fill the blue column titled Forward Rates, f(x,1), with the above code

```
                        Forward Rate
Maturity    Spot Rate     f(x,1)
 0.00         0.0200    
 0.5          0.0218    
 1.0          0.0231    
 1.5          0.0243    
 2.0          0.0253    
 2.5          0.0261    
 3.0          0.0268    
 3.5          0.0273    
 4.0          0.0277    
 4.5          0.0281    
 5.0          0.0284    
 5.5          0.0287    
 6.0          0.0289    
 6.5          0.0291    
 7.0          0.0293    
 7.5          0.0295    
 8.0          0.0296    
 8.5          0.0298    
 9.0          0.0299    
 9.5          0.0300    
 10.0         0.0301    
 10.5         0.0302    
 11.0         0.0303    
 11.5         0.0303    
 12.0         0.0304    
 12.5         0.0304
```

Comment: You should provide sample data.  I'm assuming that this is used as a WorksheetFunction.  You should also state what the procedure is trying to do.  There is probably a built in function for this purpose.  Possible [More Forward Rates Lessons: How to calculate Forward Rates – Calculations walk through](https://financetrainingcourse.com/education/2012/01/more-forward-rates-lessons-how-to-calculate-forward-rates-calculations-walk-through/)

Comment: Hi TinMan, I've just edited my question to include the data. Thanks for your reply, hopefully you can help. I'm aware it is easier to simply type out the calculation in Excel itself but I'm keen to get a grasp on VBA, especially user-defined functions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never assign any values to `Maturities()` or `SpotRates`.  You don't really need these variables as long as the range is a single row or column.   `SpotRates(1)` will return the first cell in the range,  `SpotRates(2)` the second.

```
Function OneYearFwdRates(Mty As Range, Spots As Range) As Double()
    Dim OYFR() As Double                            'OYFR stands for One Year Forward Rates'
    ReDim OYFR(1 To Spots.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
    Dim i

    For i = 2 To Spots.Rows.Count - 2
        OYFR(i, 1) = (1 + Spots(i + 2)) ^ (Mty(i + 2)) _
                  / (1 + Spots(i)) ^ (Mty(i)) - 1
        ' Debug.Print Spots(i), Mty(i)
    Next i
    OneYearFwdRates = OYFR
End Function
```

This Function is returns an Array and need to be entered like an any other Array Formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: TinMan, your code is much more concise but the results are still all zeros. In regards to your comment about not assigning values to  Dim Maturities(), I redefined the variable with  ReDim Maturities(Mty.Rows.Count)  - is this incorrect?

Comment: Ok, good to know. However, do you have any ideas why the (new and improved) code is producing zeros?

Comment: Great, your code now works. You're a legend, thanks very much TinMan.

Comment: Lol..you  must be confusing me with my cousin...from OZ :)

Comment: @AJD Fair dinkum mate!!